# Simple XML parsing

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a simple way of parsing XML within iPhone app's?

I have been using NSXMLParser and I have heard of libxml2 - I am correct in stating that these are my only two options.

I just don't want to go down a long road when there is something simply that I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [blogpost](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) gives a great overview of the most common XML parser available for iPhone (build - in and 3rd - party)

Answer (score 2):

There is also [TouchXML](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchXML) which is nice and straight forward.