# Parsing XML file with NSXMLParser - getting values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, ios, nsxmlparser

I've got a XML file which contains some data I would like to use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<items>
<item name="product" price="19.95" where="store">
This is the first product.
</item>

<item name="product2" price="39.95" where="online">
This is the second product.
</item>

<item name="product3" price="99.95" where="garagesale">
This is the third product.
</item>

</items>
```

If I made 4 arrays, one for the name, one for the price, one for where it was bought and one for its description, how would I get the data into the arrays?

I figured using NSXMLParser, but couldn't get `name`, `price`, `where` or the description.

I'm stuck on how to do this.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you read [the guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/HandlingElements.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best approach for XML parsing on the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842292/best-approach-for-xml-parsing-on-the-iphone) or [Simple XML Parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395237/simple-xml-parsing) or [Parsing XML Code on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616447/parsing-xml-code-on-iphone-sdk) or [Parsing XML in Cocoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089737/parsing-xml-in-cocoa) or [NSXMLParser on iPhone how do I use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964503/). Take your pick.

Comment: This is a good tutorial,but One thing I didn't get help. Can you tell me please that how I can read string "This is the first product".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First you need to create an object that does the parsing. It will instatiate the [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instance, set itself as the [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for the parser and then call the parse message. It can also be responsible for storing your four result arrays:

```
NSXMLParser * parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:_data];
[parser setDelegate:self];
BOOL result = [parser parse];
```

The message you are most interested in implementing in your delegate objects is [didStartElement](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSXMLParserDelegate/parser%3adidStartElement%3anamespaceURI%3aqualifiedName%3aattributes%3a). This guy gets called for each element in your XML file. In this callback you can add your name, price & where attributes to their respective arrays.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    // just do this for item elements
    if(![elementName isEqual:@"item"])
        return;

    // then you just need to grab each of your attributes
    NSString * name = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"name"];

    // ... get the other attributes

    // when we have our various attributes, you can add them to your arrays
    [m_NameArray addObject:name];

    // ... same for the other arrays
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've now got some understanding of NSXMLParser.

Comment: @jack-greenhill No problems :)

Answer (score 5):

To get the value between the tags (e.g. "This is the first product.") you can override - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to do this? I have the exact requirement .i.e., to get the value between the tags.

Answer (score 3):

in the follwing method

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        NSString *name=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *price=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"price"];
        NSString *where=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"where"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to consider the dictionary of item tag as an array and three tag (name,price and where)as the object at index 0,1,2