# iOS: NSXMLParser get attribute

Tags: xcode, ios5, nsxmlparser

I'm really new to this and I'm trying to read an RSS feed, and so far everything is good. This is how I do it:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
    [item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
    [item setObject:currentLink forKey:@"link"];
    [item setObject:currentSummary forKey:@"summary"];
    [item setObject:currentDate forKey:@"date"];
    [item setObject:currentImage forKey:@"enclosure"];

    [stories addObject:[item copy]];
    NSLog(@"adding story: %@", currentTitle);
  }
}
```

The problem is the enclosure. Which looks like this in the XML:

```
<enclosure length="150" url="urltoimage.jpg" type="image/jpeg" />
```

How do I get **url** attribute from that element from within my function?

**EDIT** The XML looks like this:

```
<item>
    <title>...</title>
    <link>...</link>
    <description>...</description>
    <pubDate>...</pubDate>
    <enclosure length="150" url="urltoimage.jpg" type="image/jpeg" />
</item>
```

And my foundCharacters function looks like this:

```
- (void)parser: (NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
  if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
    [currentTitle appendString:string];
  } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
    [currentLink appendString:string];
  } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
    [currentSummary appendString:string];
  } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
    [currentDate appendString:string];
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081629/parsing-xml-file-with-nsxmlparser-getting-values

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    // just do this for item elements
    if(![elementName isEqual:@"enclosure"])
        return;

    // then you just need to grab each of your attributes
    NSString * name = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"];

    // ... get the other attributes

    // when we have our various attributes, you can add them to your arrays
    [m_NameArray addObject:name];

    // ... same for the other arrays
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to handle one more callback for tracking attributes:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
```

`attributeDict` is dictionary with all found element arguments

Comment: Oh sweet thank you! Too bad you can't accept two answers...+1 anyways!