# Parse a very simple XML string into an NSDictionary

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xml, nsdictionary

I want to parse a very simple `XML` string into an `NSDictionary` so that I can easily access the attributes.

```
RecurrenceInfo: "<RecurrenceInfo Start="12/24/2013 01:00:00" End="01/03/2014 01:00:00" DayNumber="24" WeekOfMonth="0" WeekDays="62" Id="49409301-c3ec-43f0-8571-ca42258e8a6f" Month="12" OccurrenceCount="9" Range="1" />",
```

I was looking around and found some libraries, but then I still need to implement lot of things. Anybody know if this can be done more easy ?

kind regards

Comment: kissXML is best and required minimal code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6081782/935381

Comment: I also made a block based NSXMLParser wrapper for converting XML to NSDictionary. You can check if it fits your needs: https://github.com/erkanyildiz/EYXML2NSDictionary

Answer (score 5):

There is a good wrapper class written on top NSXMLParser. Just pass the XML String. It will convert into NSDictionary.

https://github.com/amarcadet/XMLReader

Comment: I recommend this solution.  It is the XML equivalent to the `NSJSONSerialization` class.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a third party library. Use one of the built in ones:

- NSXMLParser
- libxml2

For this case, you'd be better off using NSXMLParser, there are plenty of examples available, but the official documentation is at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000186i

You should create a class of your own specifically to parse your type of XML string using NSXMLParser. It could return an instance of itself or perhaps an NSDictionary. Up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Create the object of `NSXMLParser`.

```
NSXMLParser *myParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData]; 
[myParser setDelegate:self]; 
[myParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];
[myParser parse];
[myParser release];
```

In the delegate method you will find attribute dictionary.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser
didStartElement:(NSString*)elementName
 namespaceURI:(NSString*)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString*)qualifiedName
   attributes:(NSDictionary*)attributeDict;
```

Here `attributeDict` will have all the attributes.