# Xml parsing problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<product>  
<productname>  ----->Dynamic node
  </title>     
  </price>  
  </desc> 
</productname>  
<productname>  ---->Dynamic node
  </title> 
  </price> 
  </desc> 
</productname>  
</product>
```

productname node is dynamic depends on our request.

how to get the name of the element (productname) and the values of an element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best approach for XML parsing on the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842292/best-approach-for-xml-parsing-on-the-iphone) or [Simple XML Parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395237/) or [Parsing XML Code on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616447/) or [Parsing XML in Cocoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089737/) or [NSXMLParser on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964503/). Take your pick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [touch xml](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/source/browse/TouchXML/Common/Source/?r=SmallSocietyFork_20090625_1) by Jonathan Wight.